# "I was supposed to get off TWO STATIONS BACK" Is it valid?

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english

> My dad had told me to get off at **station 5** but I got off at **station 7.**

Can I say it like:

> I was supposed to get off **two stations back?**

Is the opposite also true, ie.

> I was supposed to get off **two stations ahead?**

Note: **I am talking about railway station.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with that sentence. I've definitely heard the word "*back*" used in that context before. I've also heard and would personally use the word "*ago*," though maybe it's restricted to periods of time only: I can't find a corresponding example sentence in the dictionary.

> I was supposed to get off two stations **ago**...

Now, if the stations are arranged such that *Station 1* is first, *Station 2* is second, and so on, the opposite is **not** true, unless you start at *Station 7* and go in the opposite direction.

Comment: Can I say: "... two stations later"?

Comment: @user100323  No: since the opposite is not true, any word that indicates that you got off too **early** (two stations _later_, two stations _ahead_, two stations _past_, etc) can't be used. If you want to use those words, you'll need to turn _**was supposed to get off**_ into _**got off**_, because you didn't intend to (weren't supposed to) get off at the wrong station.

Comment: @user100323 You could use it if you actually had gotten off the train too early.